# Activate an Excel ComAddin from C# code

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-addins

In fact, I have a C# application that is runned.
When it's launched, it runs an excel instance and save it to a variable :
`excelApp = new Excel.Application();`

Then I cycle through each of the excel's addins to find my own created added :

```
    private void getAddin()
    {
        const string addinName = "myAddInName";

        foreach (Office.COMAddIn addin in excelApp.COMAddIns)
            if (addin.Description.ToUpper().Contains(addinName.ToUpper()))
            {
                myAddin = addin;
                return;
            }
    }
```

The problem is that, it may happens that my plugin is in the deactivated elements list. (Due to some crash)

Then I must go to (on excel's frame)  :
`File >Options >AddIns >Manage >Deactivated elements >Achieve >"myAddin" >Activate`
to get my addin working again (after excel's restart)...

I tried using an addin's property to reactivate it but may app crashes again in that case.

```
            myAddin.Connect = loadAddin;
```

Someone has an idea on how to resolve it / auto-reactivate a disabled plugin using C# ?

Answer (score 3):

This should help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa662931(v=office.11).aspx

I believe you need to do

```
if(!myAddin.Connect)
{
     myAddin.Connect =true;
}
```